# Searching for a USB camera which can rotate to check a whole plane

Tags: usb, camera, rotate, 3d-graphics, api

I'm looking for a USB camera which can check 180 degrees on 2 axises.

To make this a programming question, I'll ask for a good camera which can check 360 degrees on 2 axis with a good API.

How can I achieve that with a computer?

Edit :

I'd like to have the user check the camera for me instead of programming it correctly in 3d vision. 3d vision is rather hard to get to work perfectly so for now I'd like to concentrate on having the robot behaving correctly

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the application is, but in robotic vision it is common to use a single fixed camera which is pointed straight up at a parabolic mirror.  The shape of the mirror gives a reflected image of every direction at once, without any moving parts.

The downside is that the image is distorted, and depending on what you need to do with the image might require more complex manipulation.

Comment: this downside isn't really one, just use a decent integrated graphics platform and map the image to a sphere/parabolic shape using the gfx-engine